# How to open Aurora DB Port only for Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, elastic-load-balancer

I am running the load balancer for ec2 machines and there is separate  Aurora RDS is running. They both are in same region. I want to open rds default port only for aws classic load balancer. I am can't find the option in security group and there is no IP for load balancer for which I can open port for RDS. Please help me to resolve this issue. I want to open the port of RDS only for my loadbalacer not for all in RDS security group. Can someone please help to resolve this issue? 
Thanks

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense. Load balancers don't connect directly to RDS databases. Are you perhaps trying to allow the EC2 instances behind the load balancer to connect to the Aurora database? In general you want to enter security group IDs in security group rules when possible, instead of hard-coding IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. I think I should enter the each ec2 machine IP in RDS security group. This will solve my problem.

Comment: That will work, but you should simply create one rule that references the ID of the security group the EC2 instances belong to, instead of listing each IP separately. That way when you add new instances via autoscaling they will automatically have access to the database.

Comment: Yeah did the same. I specify the security  group id of my ec2 machine in RDS security group and it working expected for me. Thanks Man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of this problem is to specify the security group id of you ec2 machines in RDS inbound security rule. Thanks @MarkB